# Button's position drops when having an element before it

Tags: html, css, button

I have a div which have a text and then a button. but the button's position drops down by a few pixels when I add an element before it.

The html:

```
<div id="profile-header-bottom">
<span id="thetitle">My website</span><button class="action-button">Add to friends</button>
</div>
```

The css:

```
#profile-header-bottom{position:relative;width:935px;height:40px;background-color:#F0F0FF;margin:auto;padding-left:10px;}
#thetitle{font-family:arial;font-size:25px;}
.action-button{border:1px solid #000080;background-color:#AAAACC;}
```

that's the result I get:
[image]

the only way I can make the button positioned correctly at the top of the div is to give it an absolute position. that's the result I want:

[image]

How can I obtain this result without making the button's position absolute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
span, button {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: lol good answer, i posted mine because i didn't see this one. Good Job @Othuna for accepting the correct one

Answer (score 2):

The correct code for this would be:

```
.action-button {
    /*
    Insert rest of css.
    */
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

EDIT: It works by setting both of the 'anchor point' to the middle of the object, rather than wherever it is by default. So with the code above you put the two middle points against each other, instead of two random points.

I added a MS Paint picture explaining it further.[image: Visualized]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the css item:

```
vertical-align:middle
```

and put it in the button's class or style tag and then add it to the text